# Populate DropDownList with ArrayList set Text and Data Fields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist with queried data based on the selection of another dropdownlist. My first query returns a list of IDs using the following code:

```
Dim selectQuery = (From train In trainerEntities.TrainerTrainingCompanies
    Where train.TrainingCompanyID = trainingCompany.ID
    Select train.TrainerID).ToList()
```

I then create an arraylist and a second query

```
Dim trainers As New ArrayList

For Each trainerID In selectQuery
    Dim selectQuery2 = (From pers In trainerEntities.Persons
                        Where pers.Person_ID = trainerID
                        Select pers.Person_ID, pers.Last_Name).ToList()
    trainers.Add(selectQuery2)
Next
```

Finally I use the arraylist as a datasource and bind the data

```
TrainerDropDownList.DataSource = trainers
TrainerDropDownList.DataBind()
```

The list populates, but not with any data. It looks like this:

```
System.Collections.Gerneric.List'1[VB$AnonymousType_0'2[System.Int32,System.String]]
```

When debugging and looking at the array list I see the proper amount of items and the proper information in each specific item. Looking at what the list is populated with from above I am sure the Int32 value is the Person_ID and what I want to use for the dropdownlist value field and the String value is the Last_Name and what I want to used for the dropdownlist text field.

Using:

```
dropdownlist.DataTextField("Last_Name") 
dropdownlist.DataValueField("Person_ID")
```

produces and error on databind.

```
does not contain a property with the name 'trainers.Last_Name'
```

How do I properly use this arraylist as my datasource for my dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rethought how I was gathering the data on selectQuery2. Instead of looping through the results, I altered the "where" clause of the LINQ query to what I believe is a called a lambda expression. This allows me to use my select query and match the person IDs.

```
Dim selectQuery2 = (From pers In trainerEntities.Persons
    Where selectQuery.Any(Function(x) pers.Person_ID.Equals(x))
    Select pers.Person_ID, pers.Last_Name).ToList()
```

The where clause now essentially says select where Person_ID = any of the original selectQuery results.

From here selectQuery2 can be used as the data source with Last_Name and Person_ID as the text and value fields.

```
TrainerDropDownList.DataSource = selectQuery2
TrainerDropDownList.DataTextField = "Last_Name"
TrainerDropDownList.DataValueField = "Person_ID"
TrainerDropDownList.DataBind()
```